# How can I redirect the error message from os.system to some file?

Tags: error-handling, python-3.6, os.system

I am using the python module os to run some command line tool inside the python script/code:

```
os.system("ToolName")
```

Sometimes it may give me errors and warnings but it writes them to console. Is there a way to redirect the writing of these messages to some .txt file ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your python file name is test.py. While running on command prompt, you can give command like:

> python /test.py > /log.try:

```
example:
$python test.py > log.txt
```

This will write log file to the folder where test.py is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use logging module or os.popen("ToolName").read() output can be saved in any variable.